# Is a spoken digit dataset available?

Tags: data-request, language, audio

Is a labeled dataset of spoken digits, that means of people saying "zero", "one", "two", three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", or "nine" available?

I would also be interested in such a dataset in another language.

I want to try some speech recognition algorithms. This means the dataset should be audio files which were created by recording humans saying those digits.

Comment: The traditional data-set for this is TIDIGITS which has duration 1-7 digits, but you could just disgard the longer ones. But that is not open (and is $500). Austalk is a new dataset that has similar data (and a bunch of other stuff as it is a historical corpus of language), but again its not open (it is however free to researchers). I think all its digits are of length >5.
I am doubt such open dataset exists, otherwise Kaldi would include it.

Comment: What do you mean by "digits of length >5"?

Comment: By "Kaldi", do you mean http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/about.html?

Comment: Yes. That is Kaldi, correct. It includes a lot of example scripts/recipes for various datasets. most of which are closed. But some are open. But I do not believe any of the open ones are "Isolated Digits". By >?5, i mean thaey are strings of digts liek "Two five four nine zero", ie they have more than 5 or more digits spoken.

Comment: @Oxinabox I wrote to the TIDIGITS people and they said "Students can obtain data for free through our data scholarship program." No intention to open the data, though.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset is a free spoken digit dataset (FSDD).

As an added bonus it comes with a few useful python utility functions.

I created this dataset because I had the same problem. Please contribute to increase the dataset's size.

Answer (score 3):

[Forvo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forvo) is a collection of pronunciations by human speakers, they have a huge amount of data, and I am pretty sure they have all digits for the 20 most spoken languages.

Examples:

- http://www.forvo.com/word/seven/#en
- http://www.forvo.com/word/sieben/#de
- http://www.forvo.com/word/sept/#fr
- [http://www.forvo.com/word/七/#ja](http://www.forvo.com/word/%E4%B8%83/#ja)

[License](http://www.forvo.com/license/): BY-NC-SA 3.0

Comment: I was also going to suggest Forvo. Unfortunately, most numbers won't be replicated enough times to constitute a data set.

Answer (score 3):

How about the UCI in Arabic? Ther are not exactly audio files, but it gets the job done.
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Spoken+Arabic+Digit