# 100 Audio files (.wav) with spoken numbers (containing zero) of 100 different speakers

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, audio

I have been working on a machine learning project for speaker recognition.
I need more audio files from different speakers to improve the accuracy of my algorithm<sup>*</sup>.

I'm using the files to recognize who is speaking. It's not a speech to text algorithm.

I'm using just digits (initially only zero) to simplify my task, because it's still a proof of concept.

<sup>*I tested my machine learning with just 10 speakers and it gave me 55% accuracy. I want to add more samples to get a higher percentage.</sup>

Comment: duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4571/1511

Comment: Unfortunately, most numbers won't be replicated enough times to constitute a data set.

Comment: duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9059/1511

Comment: im working on speaker recognition but im using digits to simplify my task. i tested my machine learning with just 10 speakers and it gave me 55% accuracy i want to add more samples to get more percentage.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple datasets of spoken digits.

##### AudioMNIST

30000 audio samples of spoken digits (0-9) of 60 different speakers.
[Download](https://github.com/soerenab/AudioMNIST). [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03418)

##### Free Spoken Digit Dataset (FSDD)

5 speakers, 2,500 recordings (50 of each digit per speaker).
[Download](https://github.com/Jakobovski/free-spoken-digit-dataset)